# Обход внутренних ссылок с заданой глубиной

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, веб-скрейпинг

Не могу правильно сделать глубину погружения (что бы брало ссылку, заходило в нее и снова вытягивало ссылки и так определенное количество раз. На сколько я понимаю у меня после добавления в set нового элемента вылетает ошибка.

Так же как сделать что бы не заходило на ссылки которые уже посещались.

Не могу придумать как решить это.
Буду благодарен за помощь

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    """ This method get page html"""

    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return

    if r.status_code < 400:
        return r.text


class EmailWebCrawler:
    def __init__(self, base_url, deep):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.deep = deep
        self.links = set()
        self.all_links = set()
        self.mails = []

    def get_links(self, html):
        """ This method get page links"""

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        domain = self.base_url.split('/')

        # Получаем все ссылки с страницы
        for al in soup.find_all('a'):
            link = al.get('href')
            # print("Found link: " + link)

            # если ссылка начинается с 'http' добавляем в set
            if link.startswith(domain[0] + '//' + domain[2]):

                if link not in self.links or link not in self.all_links:
                    self.links.add(link)    # возможно update
                    self.all_links.add(link)
                # print("Adding link - " + link)

            # если ссылка начинается с '/' добавляем в set
            elif link.startswith('/'):
                join_domen = domain[0] + '//' + domain[2] + link

                if join_domen not in self.links or join_domen not in self.all_links:
                    self.links.add(join_domen)  # возможно update
                    self.all_links.add(join_domen)
                    # print("Adding link - " + join_domen)

    def get_email(self, html):
        """ This method get page email"""

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').get_text()
        all_email = re.findall(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.?[\w]+?', soup)

        for mail in all_email:
            if mail not in self.mails:
                self.mails.append(mail)
                # print(mail)

    def run(self):

        page = get_html(self.base_url)

        if self.deep == 1:
            self.get_email(page)
            print(self.mails)

        # Нужна помощь!!!
        elif self.deep > 1:
            self.get_links(page)

            while self.deep > 0:
                for link in self.links:
                    p = get_html(link)
                    self.get_links(p)

                self.deep -= 1

            for i in self.all_links:
                p1 = get_html(i)
                self.get_email(p1)
            print(self.mails)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # url = input('Enter your url: ')
    # url = int(input('Enter deep should: '))

    parse = EmailWebCrawler('https://www.python.org/', 3)
    parse.run()
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем вам два множества, когда достаточно одного, в котором собираются посещённые уникальные ссылки.